# Create procedure Informix gives syntax error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax, informix

Ia m trying to create a stored procedure that will simply return the related records based on the ID passed. Based on research I found something that led me make the Stored Proc like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procMessageMembershipSelect1 (membershipnumber char(10))
RETURNING CHAR(10) AS membership_number, SMALLINT as message_id , varchar(200) as 
message, CHAR(1) AS target, DATETIME as date_time_creation, DATETIME as 
date_time_display;
DEFINE rsMembershipNumber CHAR(10);
DEFINE rsMessageID smallint;
DEFINE rsMessage VARCHAR(200);
DEFINE rsTarget CHAR(1);
DEFINE rsDateTimeCreation datetime;
DEFINE rsDateTimeDisplay datetime;
FOREACH
SELECT membership_number, message_id, message, target,date_time_creation, 
date_time_display
INTO rsMembershipNumber, rsMessageID, rsMessage, rsTarget, rsDateTimeCreation, 
rsDateTimeDisplay
FROM MessageMembership
WHERE membership_number = membershipnumber    
ORDER BY date_time_display
RETURN rsMembershipNumber, rsMessageID rsMessage, rsTarget, rsDateTimeCreation,   
rsDateTimeDisplay WITH RESUME;
END FOREACH
END PROCEDURE;
```

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: missing the `;` at the last END FOREACH?

Comment: When I evaluate the procedure in SQL Editor it points me to 'DATETIME as date_time_creation' in the declarion part, but i have no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a precision of the datetime variables, everywhere you declare a datetime.
You also forgot a ',' in the return statement.

The correct procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procMessageMembershipSelect1 (membershipnumber char(10))
RETURNING CHAR(10) AS membership_number, SMALLINT as message_id , varchar(200) as 
message, CHAR(1) AS target, DATETIME year to fraction as date_time_creation, DATETIME          year to fraction as 
date_time_display;
DEFINE rsMembershipNumber CHAR(10);
DEFINE rsMessageID smallint;
DEFINE rsMessage VARCHAR(200);
DEFINE rsTarget CHAR(1);
DEFINE rsDateTimeCreation datetime year to fraction;
DEFINE rsDateTimeDisplay datetime year to fraction;
FOREACH
SELECT membership_number, message_id, message, target,date_time_creation, 
date_time_display
INTO rsMembershipNumber, rsMessageID, rsMessage, rsTarget, rsDateTimeCreation, 
rsDateTimeDisplay
FROM MessageMembership
WHERE membership_number = membershipnumber    
ORDER BY date_time_display
RETURN rsMembershipNumber, rsMessageID, rsMessage, rsTarget, rsDateTimeCreation,   
rsDateTimeDisplay WITH RESUME;
END FOREACH
END PROCEDURE;
```